# How to express analogy between two pairs of entities?

Tags: syntax, analogy

What is the correct way of expressing analogy? I am looking for the general pattern of something like this:

> Kitten is to cat what a puppy to a dog.

I have seen **as** being use sometimes instead of **what**. Analogy grammar is a bit confusing for me. What are the general patterns of expressing analogy?

Comment: I would use "as" or "the same as", but it is probably a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern is

> *something* is to *something* **as** *something else* is to *something else*
>   *something* is to *something* **what** *something else* is to *something else*
>
> Kitten is to cat **as** puppy is to dog.
>   Hunger is to food **what** thirst is to liquid.

In your example, you are missing the parallel construction which is necessary

> Kitten is to cat what a puppy to a dog. *( not quite right )*
>
> Kitten is to cat what puppy **is** to dog. *( better )*
>   A kitten is to a cat what a puppy is to a dog.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. Putting `is` before `what` comes naturally to my mind. But it seems incorrect according to your answer.